# How can I efficiently test whether a subsets of nodes in a DAG are "lined up" more often than expected by random chance?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, permutation-test, dag

I have a directed acyclic graph with N nodes, each of which is assigned to one of K groups, with K < N. My hypothesis is that nodes in the same group tend to "line up" along a linear path. Specifically, if we define a connected pair of nodes as a pair for which either one is reachable from the other, I want to test whether the set of all pairs of nodes with the same group as each other contains more connected pairs than would be expected if the group labels were assigned at random. Obviously, one straightforward way to test this would be to compute the above statistic for a large number of group label permutations and derive an empirical p-value for the observed statistic. However, this might be computationally prohibitive if I want to compute permutation p-values for a large number of such DAGs. Is there a more clever way to test this hypothesis without having to perform a large number of permutations?

One possibility I have considered is treating "same group" and "connected" as two categorical variables with 2 levels each (yes/no) and using a one-sided Fisher's exact test to determine whether the yes answers are enriched for each other, but I don't know whether this is valid, since these are categorizations of pairs of nodes rather than individual nodes, and both the "same group" and connectedness categorizations of different pairs are clearly related (e.g. "same group" is a transitive relation).

Comment: Addendum: I tried the Fisher test and the naively-implemented permutation test, and the Fisher test is indeed invalid (gives too small p-values), for the reason given above. I am still interested in an efficient algorithm that performs similarly to the permutation test.